# El Capitan: Your iCloud session has expired

Tags: itunes, macos

After upgrading to 10.11, everytime when I run iTunes get this:
[image]
Enter login and password, fix for 20 minutes. How can this be fixed?

What I did:

- reset NVRAM.

Comment: And your question is? Also, what have you already done to fix the problem?

Comment: Given that I don't have an iCloud account, don't want one, and don't care about iCloud, this popup was especially annoying.  Sometimes I think that "Think different" means "Think exactly like our product managers think you should think."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found an advice for this on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/3nglyc/your_icloud_session_has_expired_popup_is_pissing/): *Log out of iTunes Store account and log back in*.

Comment: Seems it helped.